# github how to fix error: refname refs/heads/new_branch not found

Tags: git, github

I'm really new to GitHub.

I made my first project and want to add it to GitHub. But when I try to add my project to GitHub I'm getting the following error and I couldn't find a way to fix it.

`git branch -M main`

> error: refname refs/heads/new_branch not found
>
> fatal: Branch rename failed

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

[`git branch -M`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch#Documentation/git-branch.txt--m) is for renaming a branch.

If makes sense if you have a current `master` branch that you want to rename as `main`.

Make sure that your new local project has:

- <del>at least one commit</del> ([Nikolaos Kakouros](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1422681/nikolaos-kakouros) mentions [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64974547/github-how-to-fix-error-refname-refs-heads-new-branch-not-found#comment130296345_64991939) it is not required anymore, at least with Git 2.37+)
- done on a `master` branch
- pushed with `git push -u origin master`

Comment: Thanks. It really  helped me a lot

Comment: Having at least one commit in your branch before renaming it is not required anymore (tested with git 2.37).

Comment: @NikolaosKakouros Thank you for the feedback. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 7):

I solved this thanks to this [guide](http://www.henryxi.com/git-refname-refs-heads-master-not-found),

Apparently and I do not know why the steps given by the Github guide are not in the correct order and if I am wrong that someone please explain to me.

I solved it with these steps:

```
    git init
    git remote add origin git@github.com:<YOUR_REPOSITORY_ADDRESS>
    git add .
    git commit -m "first commit" 
    git branch -M main
    git push -u origin main
```

steps that the guithub guide gives that for me was a mistake.

```
echo "# socialdata" >> README.md
git init
git add README.md
git commit -m "first commit"
git branch -M main
git remote add origin https://github.com/<YOUR_REPOSITORY_ADDRESS>
git push -u origin main
```

Comment: The reason your steps worked because you already had "README.md" file available in your local repository.  If no files presented, `git add .` would not work and `git branch -M main` would not work either.

Answer (score 1):

add the files in the repository to track

```
git add .
```

commit at least once before pushing it to the origin

```
git commit -m "<your commit message>"
```

now try renaming the branch

```
git branch -M main
```

you can further add origin if not already added

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/<YOUR_REPOSITORY_ADDRESS>
```

and push it to github

```
git push -u origin main
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was because you did not have any commit. In other words, you must add some files using `git add .` and `git commit -m "first commit"` before trying to `git branch -M main`.